# mock ontouchstart event in window object jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, window

I'm trying to mock ontouchstart event in window object to make some tests, but i can't find a proper way to do it

```
export const main = () =>
  !!('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints);
```

I try to do

```
 it('123', () => {
    const spyWindowOpen = jest.spyOn(window, 'ontouchstart');
    spyWindowOpen.mockImplementation(jest.fn());
  });
```

but ontouchstart does not seem exist on window object in my compilation tests

Comment: Can you provide the code under test? what test result did you get? What do you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok i do that :

```
describe('support ontouchstart', () => {
  it('return true when window support ontouchstart event', () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-global-assign
    window = {
      ontouchstart: jest.fn(),
    };

    expect(!!('ontouchstart' in window)).toBe(true);
  });
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to reset to window in original position back like below.

```
it('should render', () => {
const original = window.ontouchstart;
window.ontouchstart = jest.fn();   

// rest of your code like 
// expect(!!('ontouchstart' in window)).toBe(true);

window.ontouchstart = original;
```

});